# How to read a text file with tokens and save each token content in array of objects Java

Tags: java, file-io, token

I'm trying to read tokens and its values in a multiline text file, that has a format I specify bellow, so far I've read the file with Scanner and with a regular expression I'm able to differentiate the tokens (because they will always have the word "process" followed by a number). This is an example of the desired result.

```
objects[
        [process0, [1,2,3,4,5]], 
        [process1, [6,7,8,9,10]], 
        [process2, [1,2]]
 ]
```

I want to place the following line inside the while loop to clean the array every time after adding a new object to the list of objects (since my approach of having a while loop in the else block didn't work, I left it outside and I didn't include that loop)

```
List<String> process_numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
```

My idea is to read a token then take the numbers before the next token and store them in an object and then adding the object to the list of objects, so basically I need help with that.

Note: I'm clearly not good at Java, feel free to suggest ways to improve my code.

Main.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
         File f = new File("processes.txt");
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

         List<Objects> objects = new ArrayList<Objects>();
         String process_name = " ";
         List<String> process_numbers = new ArrayList<String>();

         while(sc.hasNextLine()){

            String line = sc.nextLine();
            if (line.matches(".*process.*")){
                process_name = line;
                //System.out.println("PROCESS NAME: " + line);
            }else{
                process_numbers.add(line);
                //System.out.println("NUMBER: " + line);
            }

            Objects o = new Objects(process_name, process_numbers);
            objects.add(o);
        }

      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
}
```

Objects.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Objects {
    private String process_name;
    List<String> process_numbers = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Objects(String process_name, List<String> process_numbers){
      this.process_name = process_name;
      this.process_numbers = process_numbers;
    }

    public String getProcess_name() {
      return process_name;
    }

    public void setProcess_name(String process_name) {
     this.process_name = process_name;
    }

    public List<String> getProcess_numbers() {
     return process_numbers;
    }

    public void setProcess_numbers(List<String> process_numbers) {
     this.process_numbers = process_numbers;
    }

 }
```

processes.txt

```
process0
1
2
3
4
5
process1
6
7
8
9
10
process2
1
2
```

EDIT:

I have modified the while loop this way:

```
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {

            String line = sc.nextLine();
            List<String> process_numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (line.matches(".*process.*")) {
                process_name = line;
                line = sc.nextLine();
            }

            while (!line.matches(".*process.*") && sc.hasNextLine()) {
                process_numbers.add(line);
                line = sc.nextLine();
            }

            Objects o = new Objects(process_name, process_numbers);
            objects.add(o);

        }

        for(Objects obj : objects) {
            System.out.println(obj.getProcess_name());
            System.out.println(obj.getProcess_numbers());

        }
```

I'm kind of getting the result I want but with some problems, first the name of the processes are all the same ("process0") and the program is not printing the very last number of the text file.

Result so far

```
process0
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
process0
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
process0
[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it, but you were always skiping the line with process name

```
String line = sc.nextLine();
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    List<String> process_numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (line.matches(".*process.*")) {
        process_name = line;
        line = sc.nextLine();
    }

    while (!line.matches(".*process.*") && sc.hasNextLine()) {
        process_numbers.add(line);
        line = sc.nextLine();
    }
    if(!sc.hasNextLine()){
         process_numbers.add(line);
    }

    Objects o = new Objects(process_name, process_numbers);
    objects.add(o);

}
```

Output:

```
process0
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
process1
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
process2
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't solve my problem, because it doesn't work for the rest of processes with different names also because it's adding each number separately to the object. What I'm trying to do is to group the numbers by token and save the object in the array of objects. Anyway your answer gave me some ideas that made my code work a bit better but I'm still having some trouble.